# Shows the Apache directory structure instead of my app

Tags: php, cakephp, apache2

I am working on my first CakePHP project, and I have done the following:

- Downloaded the CakePHP source from (http://cakephp.org/)
- rename to sampleapp and copy the entire folder to /var/www/html
- sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart

And when I go `http://localhost` it shows the correct Apache welcome page for Centos. But when I go to `http://localhost/sampleapp` it shows me the directory structure

```
http://localhost/sampleapp

Parent Directory         -   
app/    05-Jan-2013 14:20    -   
build.properties    05-Jan-2013 14:20   177  
build.xml   05-Jan-2013 14:20   8.6K     
html/   05-Jan-2013 14:20    -   
index.php   05-Jan-2013 14:20   1.4K     
lib/    05-Jan-2013 14:20    -   
plugins/    05-Jan-2013 14:20    -   
vendors/    05-Jan-2013 14:20
```

What am I missing here? I have checked that the .htaccess file is also there

With some SO research I added the following line to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

and restart the Apache but it didn't work.

I'm using

- Apache2
- CakePHP 2.2.4
- Centos

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should disable the Indexes of Apache.

After that make sure php is loaded by Apache.

`httpd -l` and `httpd -M` and search for 'php' or similar.

I am not sure about cake-php but in symfony2 the document-root is `/root-to-page/web`

And if cake-php uses `.htaccess` files you must change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in your vHost or Server settings